# Wix uninstalls entire website not just application

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer

I've got this below but I want to change it in such a way that it installs the web application to an existing web site. Currently it installs the website and all the files but then on uninstall also removes all the files, I just want it to add the files as a web applications. How so I go about doing this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLLOCATION">
      <Component Id="C_IISWebsite" Guid="{138B3868-24E8-4D7B-8793-0D254AF349D4}" KeyPath="yes">
        <!-- This does not create a user, it's just an object that's referenced by the WebAppPool component -->
        <util:User Id="WebAppPoolUser" CreateUser="no" Name="[WEB_APP_POOL_IDENTITY_USERNAME]"
                   Password="[WEB_APP_POOL_IDENTITY_PWD]" Domain="[WEB_APP_POOL_IDENTITY_DOMAIN]"/>

        <!-- The "Identity" attritbute below needs to be set to "other" to use the util:User defined above -->
        <iis:WebAppPool Id="WebAppPool" Name="[WEB_APP_POOL_NAME]" Identity="other" User="WebAppPoolUser"/>

        <iis:WebSite Id="DefaultWebSite" Description="[WEBSITE_NAME]" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION" >
          <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="80"/>
        </iis:WebSite>

        <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="My.VirtualDir" Alias="mdxWebSite" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION" WebSite="DefaultWebSite">
          <iis:WebApplication Id="Application" Name="mdxWebSite" WebAppPool="WebAppPool" />
        </iis:WebVirtualDir>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem has to do with the installer not knowing what to uninstall, and therefore removes the default or parent web site.  Take a look at [this sample by John Robbins](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2011/02/23/web-application-installer-in-wix.aspx), the key is to store the configuration in the registry so the uninstall knows what to remove, doing the following inside your `<Component> ... </Compoonent>` element should do it, don't forget to insert your appropriate names/data and guid.

```
<!--The component for installer properties I need to save so they can be used on the uninstall.-->
<Component Id="SetupRegistryValues" Guid="{...}" KeyPath="yes" >
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\CompanyName\ProductName\Install" Name="WebAppName" Value="[WEB_APP_NAME]" Type="string" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\CompanyName\ProductName\Install" Name="WebSiteName" Value="[WEBSITE_NAME]" Type="string" />
```

Comment: This is only a part of "Remember property" pattern described by Rob Mensching in his blog: http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern. It's a recommended approach to the problems when you need to store the value between installation sessions (install / uninstall / upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install your web application & virtual directories to an existing website and also don’t want to delete your website while uninstalling the product; then define your website under a separate fragment (not inside any Component). As below:

```
  <Fragment>
    <iis:WebSite Id="XYZ_WebSite" Description="Default Web Site">
      <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="80" />
    </iis:WebSite>
  </Fragment>
```

Now define components to deploy your web applications\Vdirs and refer this site ID from  nodes, as below:

```
<iis:WebVirtualDir Id="XYZ_VirtualDirectory_A" Alias="MyXYZ_V_ DIR" Directory="[MYDIR]" WebSite="XYZ_WebSite">
```